# Keypad 4*4 with Arduino

Tags: if-statement, arduino, key, interrupt, keypad

I am using keypad 4*4 with an Arduino Mega, I have sensors connected to the Arduino I want to press a key from the keypad and have response in the same time, I don't want to wait till the loop continue, I want to save up to 10 numbers entered from the keypad, so is there a way to make the keypad as an interrupt for my code?

```cpp
void loop()
{
    char key = kpd.getKey();
    if (key != NO_KEY) {
        if (key == 'C') //clear the array
        {
            index = 0;
            numbers[index] = '\0';
        }
        else if (key == '.') {
            numbers[index++] = '.';
            numbers[index] = '\0';
        }
        else if (key >= '0' && key <= '9') {
            for (int z = 0; z == 10; z++) {
                numbers[index++] = key;
                numbers[index] = '\0';
            }
        }
        else if (key == 'A') {
            float len = atof(numbers); //conversion from string to numeric
            if (fona.callPhone(numbers)) {
                Serial.println(F("RING!"));
                Serial.print(F("Phone Number: "));
                Serial.println(numbers); //print out on serial monitor
            }
        }
        else if (key == 'D') {
            if (fona.pickUp()) {
                Serial.println(F("Failed"));
            }
        }
        else if (key == '#') {
            if (fona.hangUp()) {
                Serial.println(F("Failed"));
            }
        }
    }

    gas = analogRead(gasPin);
    dtostrf(gas, 4, 2, gass);
    Serial.println(gas);
    delay(1000); // Print value every 1 sec.

    val = digitalRead(inputPin); // read input value
    if (val == HIGH) { // check if the input is HIGH
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn LED ON
        delay(150);
        if (pirState == LOW) {
            // we have just turned on
            Serial.println("Motion detected!");
            // We only want to print on the output change, not state
            pirState = HIGH;
        }
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED OFF

        delay(300);
        if (pirState == HIGH) {
            // we have just turned off
            Serial.println("Motion ended!");
            // We only want to print on the output change, not state
            pirState = LOW;
        }
    }
    int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);

    if (ldrStatus <= 550) {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        Serial.println("LDR is DARK, LED is ON");
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    }
    valee = analogRead(tempPin);
    float cel = (valee * 0.48828125) / 2.12304;
    dtostrf(cel, 4, 2, temp);
    Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
    Serial.print(cel);
    Serial.print("*C");
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
```

Comment: absolutely, but simplest possible way will be to use your own code to handle  keystroke instead of using matrix keyboard library.

Comment: also, why do you want to use interrupt? you can reduce delay (1000) to say delay(10) to make it more responsive!

Comment: I have tried it and it is the same i used this code and still have the same problem i need something to get out from the void to keypad

Comment: {

  if (millis() - kdelay > period) //used to make non-blocking delay
  {
    kdelay = millis(); //capture time from millis function
    switch (keypad())  //switch used to specify which button
    {
      case 0:
        {
          numbers[index++] = '1';
          numbers[index] = '\0';
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        {
          numbers[index++] = '2';
          numbers[index] = '\0';
        }
        break;